How can you pay online for Indonesian visa applications?
I've applied for a C1 (formerly known as 211A) 60-day Indonesian visa, because these aren't offered on arrival, and I don't want the hassle of having to go in person somewhere to extend my 30-day visa.
After finishing the application, the site says it's "Waiting For Payment" but there's no button/link/anything to pay. Others have noticed this as well on reddit, but the thread was archived, in reddit's infinite wisdom.
At the bottom there's a "Print Invoice" (why I'd need one beats me) button, which generates a PDF. In the PDF there's a "billing code", and a link to "Simponi" (a government payment system? Can't tell, the site is in Indonesian only, and the "text" on it is mostly an image, so Google Translate doesn't work). I used ChatGPT to copy/paste and translate, clicked on the Registration link to access the sign-up form, and it starts with:

Which translates to "Application User Types":

[ ] MINISTRY/AGENCY USER BILLING
[ ] USER BILLING OF NON-OIL AND GAS RESOURCES

I suppose I'm a "ministry user billing"? I read the visa application manual, but the page on Simponi (26 or 16, they can't even figure out page numbers) is a bunch of absolutely non-descriptive useless buraucratic government garbage, so I was left without help, and got stuck at this part:

ChatGPT said:

"NPWP (Nomor Pokok Wajib Pajak): This is an Indonesian Tax Identification Number."
"KTP (Kartu Tanda Penduduk): This is an Indonesian National Identity Card."

The KTP (NIK) is their "population identification number" and has a specific format I didn't bother to reverse engineer, so I selected NPWP and entered 6 0's followed by my passport number, to meet their "15 character minimum" requirement.
Then apparently you have to select which Ministry to pay, then which "echelon" and "work unit" (?). I figured out the ministry for Imigrasi was #13, Law and Human Rights, but the other two fields won't respond to any searches:

What am I supposed to do here?
Or is this supposed to indicate MY ministry affiliation, since it's a registration form?
Further down on the form there's this, requesting a "Name of Business Entity" and the NPWP taxpayer identification number.

Also, I can't enter my US phone number because the "Nomor Handphone" field doesn't accept +.
So how is a foreigner supposed to fill the Simponi registration form?
What should I enter for:

Jenis Pengguna Aplikasi?
Identitas Pengguna - NPWP / KTP
What actual number for NPWP?
Which "Kementerian/Lembaga"?
Which "Unit Eeleson I"?
Which "Satuan Kerja"?
Which "Nama Badan Usaha"?

(I did try using Simponi's support chat and WhatsApp, but they're a useless bot that runs in circles and doesn't let you contact a human. I've also filed a ticket, but I doubt I'll receive any useful reply.)
Below is the entire form:


I'm pretty sure the Simponi stuff is a red herring. Have you tried the steps in the Reddit thread, which lead to a much more plausible credit card form?

The Simponi was indeed a dead end. I started a new application at 9:30am Indonesian time (whether that mattered I'll never know), and after bypassing various site issues and bugs like this one, was presented with an option to pay via:

CREDIT CARD/DEBIT CARD (Foreign Bank)
INDONESIAN PAYMENT METHOD

The INDONESIAN PAYMENT METHOD was, dumbfoundingly, the default option.

I did not see the credit card option the first time I applied. Several people in the reddit thread I had linked to mentioned that the website would change from one day to the next, or depending on the time of day (whether it was accessed during working hours in Indonesia), or depending on VPNs being used. The "Pay" button appeared in some browsers but not others.
Anyway, after selecting the CREDIT CARD option and checking all the checkboxes, a "Payment" button appeared at the bottom, and I was able to pay with my US-issues credit card after confirming the transaction (3D Secure) via the finpay.id payment processor.

Later I found out that the Simponi options exists for the cottage industry of local visa middle-men services, whose existence is unsurprising (perpetuated even) given the unreliability and confusion of the official channels.

Thanks for this post. Ran into the same issue, just did a new application, and saw the correct payment button now.

Bro I had the absolut same problems. This helped me so much I hope your pillow ist always cold. Appreciate it My tip for y’all is to do it on a laptop or pc and not on a tablet or phone
